# How to grab video frames from onPreviewFrame in android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, video-processing

In my application I am using surfaceiew to take video in android. In onpreviewFrame method I have written code to grab frames, but problem is I can not get all frames of video. I am capturing around 14 second video, but I get only around 90 frames. frame rate is 30 fps and image size is 800 x 480.

The code is below to frab frames in onPreviewFrame method:

```
formattedFileCount = fileCountFormatter.format(fileCount);
jpegFile = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/abc/foo-"
                        + formattedFileCount + ".jpg");
                fileCount++;

Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
YuvImage image = new YuvImage(b,
                parameters.getPreviewFormat(), 800,
                480, null);


fos = new FileOutputStream(jpegFile);
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
image.compressToJpeg(
        new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()),
            90, bos);
```

So for around 14 second video, total frames would be 420, but i just get less than 100 frames. Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a timestamp (System.currentTimeMillis()) to check how long it takes to execute this code.  Multiply that by 30 and it should be lower than 1 second. Maybe your Android device is not that fast to convert the raw preview data to jpg and write that to disk. Where do you write it sd-card?